# Custom s3 base URLs for Vite compiled asset in Laravel App

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-vite

I'm using `Laravel 9` application. Laravel latest version has replaced `webpack` to `vite`. I was able to successfully run the app into my local environment but, while deploying the compiled assets to the `AWS S3` I'm getting `CORS` error in the browser console.

Steps I did after running in local environment.

added `ASSET_URL=https://****.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` in my `.env` file

run `npm run build`

run `aws s3 sync public/ s3://****/ --delete --exclude index.php --acl public-read`

I can see that my `.css` and other files are loaded perfectly, but I'm getting `CORS` error only in the compiled `js` file.

[image]

I also added policy in my `s3 bucket`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1617109982386",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1617109981105",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::****/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this isn't helping me out.

My `Vite` config file looks like:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

I also tried declaring cors in vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        cors: true
    }
});
```

I'm unable to find any solution. Help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue isn't fetching the script, it's the header returned by the "server" not allowing your origin/method etc. To quote "The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP headers that let servers describe which origins are permitted to read that information from a web browser." - more info; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Hey Have a look at setting CORS in the s3 bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html